# The use of "gleich" in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverb

I am currently reading a book by Uwe Timm in German called "Die Zugmaus" (by the way awesome book, you should read it, definitely worth it) and I came across this sentence, which has *gleich* in it.

> "Ich habe nie in meinem Leben so viele Katzen gesehen wie in Paris,
> und zwar die größten, schnellsten und wildesten Exemplare, die man
> sich überhaupt vorstellen kann. Erst in Paris verstand ich die wahre
> Bedeutung der Mause-Weisheit: "Eine Katze im Haus bringt Kummer und
> Graus."
>
> Hier lebten in jedem Haus **gleich** mehrere Katzen, denn die Franzosen
> haben eine grosse Vorliebe für Katzen."

When I looked up in my laptop's built-in dictionary, I found out that GLEICH has many meanings and I thought that in this paragraph it could be working as PARTIKEL.
I also watched this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Awhco_VHWE)

These are the definitions I am given when looking up in my dictionary:

a) unbetont

> Drückt in Fragesätzen aus, dass der Sprecher oder die Sprecherin nach etwas eigentlich Bekanntem fragt, an das er oder sie sich im Moment nicht erinnert, doch was hat er gleich gesagt? | wie heißt das gleich?

b) betont

> Drückt in Aussage- und Aufforderungssätzen Unmut oder Resignation aus: dann lass es gleich bleiben | wenn er nicht mitspielt, können wir gleich zu Hause bleiben

c) unbetont

> mit Negationüberhaupt

At the beginning I thought it could mean B, but on the other GLEICH resembles AUF EINMAL. I am not sure.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add, why looking up *gleich* in a dictionary didn't help you?

Comment: Seems to be a weakness of the dictionary entry, [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gleich#2) meaning 2 seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example *gleich* is not a modal particle, but an adverb (see link below). 
As to the meaning, it means "at the same time" or, more specifically, "**at the same place**". In your example, its function is rather an emphatic one. 
[See the second meaning for furhter examples.](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gleich#2)

Comment: I am a bit in doubt about the meaning. You read it practically as *gleichzeitig*, i.e. "at the same time". However, native speakers would rather understand it as as a word to give emphasize to "mehrere", like in English perhaps "**even** several cats", carrying also some attitude of the speaker (astonishment, bewilderment). And consequently you might perhaps see *gleich* as a modal particle anyway?

Comment: Well, if you have duplicate words to express the same idea, in this case "in each house many at the same place" it serves as an amplifier. So this does not contradict the reading as "at the same place".  I'll make sure to update the answer with this a bit later, thanks for your insight. 
As for modal particles, in this case gleich does not fullfill the formal requirements to be viewed as such, and is also listed as an adverb on dwds with exactly this meaning.

Comment: This is definitely a modal particle.  "gleich" meaning "equally" or "in a short time" or in any of the other adverbial senses is much less likely than simply an emphasizer roughly in the sense of "sogar".

Comment: Modalpartikeln sind aber streng genommen nicht vorfeldfähig, was gleich in unserem und ähnlichen Kontexten nicht ist: "Gleich mehrere tolle Aktionen haben die fleißigen Kids des Cecilien-Gymnasiums in Düsseldorf auf die Beine gestellt".  Wichtiger noch, es fungiert hier vielmehr als ein an "mehrere" gekettetes Verstärkungsadverb - auch wenn es tatsächlich etwas zum Sinn der gesamten Aussage beiträgt, wie auch sonstige Redemittel zur Verstärkung einer Aussage. Ansonsten finde ich es nicht überraschend, dass sich die verstärkende Verwendung vom Adverb "gleich" den modalen Partikeln ähnelt.

Comment: NS: Gleich als Modalpartikel ist in dem Sinne dem Duden und dwds nicht bekannt. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gleich_noch_doch_ueberhaupt
https://www.dwds.de/wb/gleich#2
Dass Adverbien zur Verstärkung eines anderen Wortes benutzt werden, ist für sie kein neues Phänomen und macht sie noch lange nicht zu einer Modalpartikel, wobei auch ich der Meinung bin, dass die Grenze eher verschwommen ist. (Man nehme z.B. solche Wörter wie "schön" oder "langsam").

Comment: the notion of emphasis is one I'd ascribe to "sogar" or just "gar", which I like to compare to "ja", "je". Indeed, "in jedem Haus lebten je mehrere Katzen" would work, and show yet another connotation, although translating it as "each" would be missing the point.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I see "even" used in non-idiomatic ways all the time, I'm evenen affraid I use it wrong all too often. I think your example is such a case. Nobody is reading "gleichzeitig", that is just wrong, the syntactic position of "-zeitig" is already covered by "mehrere", though functionally different (adv., adj.). Perhaps its informative to compare  the way "-self" is frequently but not always added to pronouns, useful in English of course, but redundant in German, though often added for good measure ("ich sehe mich selbst" whereas "ich sehe mich _" is rather vague). ...

Comment: ... I don't think I can make that clear, and intuition might be faulty. Let's see ... at least "selbst" naturally expresses "in the same place", "at once". It's not implied that they live *together* or *solatiry* in a social sense. That's still non-sense. "just", a usual translation of "gleich" or rather "gerade" does not quite fit either.

Answer (score 7):

The meaning in this case is 2. at https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gleich_prompt_daneben

> erstaunlicherweise auf einmal, zugleich
>
> Beispiel: gleich zwei Paar Schuhe kaufen

Which is in theory the same as the link to DWDS that @Dan posted, but it expresses astonishment at whatever is being described, in your case that there are **several** cats living in each house. That's an aspect that @ChristianGeiselmann addressed in his first comment to that answer and which, in my opinion, is missing from the DWDS entry.

To stick with the Duden example, saying

> zwei Paar Schuhe kaufen

in contrast means simply that, *to buy two pairs of shoes*, but in this case you consider it perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0):

I stipulate that the collocation of *gleich* does correspond to the place, pretty much like @Dan said, but I would venture a guess that it reflects *gelegen*, "lebten in jedem Haus gelegen mehrere ...", "in Düsseldorf gelegen". On the one hand, the etymology of *gleich* ... Oh snap, there lived *like* so many cats ...

I was trying to get to *gelegentlich*, *Gelegenheit*, and remark that "Leiche" would just not fit into the semantic field, and yada yada yada

But you just cannot argue with *like*